# Multiple network card stability through change of IP

Tags: networking

I have two network cards on a machine in production.  One of them connects to the Domain and is a static IP.  The other connects to PLC's controlling machinery.  I need to change the IP of the Domain side card.

**Question:** Will changing the Domain cards IP affect the PLC card **AT ALL?** e.g. stop/increase latency in the other network.  I don't expect that it will but it will be too expensive if I'm wrong.  Thanks.

Comment: No; The two networks as you have describe them are seperate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't write about your OS, I suspect you are using a Windows, probably Windows 7. In this case, my answer is:

1. Theoretically, not. What you are hit, it is one of the most important problems of the OSes and Windows7 can solve that relatively easily. Different devices and their configuration / reconfiguration should be done independently.
2. Practically, yes, but not very badly. It is not clear, what is running on your PLC controller, but considering that you are controlling it from a windows, I am sure, it is not really critical. A little bit of delay could happen.

---

3. There could be another danger, if your next system configuration causes some unneeded interaction between your network interfaces. For example, if your new IP is an IP on your PLC-side network. But it is in most cases some buggy configuration and I susepct you know what are you doing.

Comment: Yes it is win 7. The PLCs run production for an entire building but the new ip would stay on the domain.

Comment: @Cand3r Your problem is based on that you are using a Windows7 in a system where it is not intended to take part, even not on the opinion of the Microsoft. It is a workstation OS, in a workstation configuration, there is _no_ guarantee that it won't have any problem for that. You should use a server system for productive work. But, if it is already the situation, then the best what you can do: wait the next end of your working hours and then do it.

Comment: Yea, I understand the risks of Windows in production.  If I had any control over it things would be different.  Thanks for the input.  The whole point of the question was to determine whether or not to wait until after production to change the address.